# Delegate defined as a method's signature is not a valid substitute

Tags: c#, delegates

When I have the following example code:

```
namespace Test {
 public delegate void TestDelegate(object sender, MyEventArgs e);

 public class A {
  public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> Handler;

  public void Test(){
   Handler += B.Observe;
  }
 }
}

public class B {
 public void Observe(TestDelegate) {
  // Do something
 }
}
```

I get the error

> *No overload for 'Observe' matches delegate
>   'System.EventHandler'*

However, when I use

`Observer(object sender, MyEventArgs e){}`

it works just fine. It was my understanding that a delegate can be used to define a method signature in multiple places, what's the problem in this scenario?

Comment: It's exactly how you understood. The problem here is that you use your delegate as a parameter. The definition is not "copied"... In other words, the "Observer" method has to match the signature of the delegate, not take a delegate as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/900fyy8e%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) define the signature:

```
public delegate void TestDelegate(object sender, MyEventArgs e);

public event TestDelegate MyEvent;
```

the handler of the event must have the same signature of the delegate:

```
MyEvent += MyEventHandler;

void X_Sample_MyEvent(object sender, MyEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

you can pass wathever type you want:

```
public delegate void AnotherDelegate();
public delegate void TestDelegate(AnotherDelegate arg);

MyEvent += X_Sample_MyEvent;

void X_Sample_MyEvent(AnotherDelegate arg) { }
```

or maybe something like this:

```
public delegate void TestDelegate(object sender, MyEventArgs e);

MyEvent += (sender, e) =>
{
    Observe(MyEvent);
};

void Observe(TestDelegate arg)
{
}
```

Comment: My reason to use the delegate was to replace the parameters in `X_Sample_MyEvent` by `TestDelegate`. Is this possible? When I do this, I get the same error as before.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: The delegate in other terms, is just a function pointer. The usage that you specified does not sound valid.

Comment: What do you get with this?

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria: your last proposal works exactly as I want it to! However, how can I now access the parameters that are behind this delegate parameter?

Answer (score 1):

The signature of the method `Observer` does not match the signature of the method `EventHandler`.

(EventHandler is a .NET delegate type under System namespace)

You could do this:

```
public event TestDelegate Handler;
```

instead of

```
public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> Handler; //Notice the type of Handler. Its of type EventHandler defined under System namespace.
```

Comment: @Jeroen: They work like a function pointer. you cannot use a "delegate" instead of function parameters. They dont work like that way

Comment: Is there perhaps a different language feature that does what I want? Maybe it's an X-Y issue.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: Perhaps you could define the method `Observer` as a delegate and point that to an another method meeting your requirements. And also, i don't really understand why do you need this feature?

Comment: Or if you want the same `substitution` why not thinking about some .NET based MACROS ?